# JS regular expression, basic lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I cannot figure out, for the life of me, why this regular expression

```
^\.(?=a)$
```

does not match

```
".a"
```

anyone know why?

I am going off the information provided here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: obviously, the quotation characters " are there just to designate the character string

Comment: Double your backslash.

Comment: like \\.(?=a)$ .... why is that?

Comment: Yes, like that.  Backslash is special in JS strings.   The page you linked to says "*Do not forget to escape \ itself while using the RegExp("pattern") notation because \ is also an escape character in strings.*"

Comment: @JohnHascall - that only applies if the OP is creating the regex from a string. Which isn't mentioned in the question one way or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because the lookahead doesn't actually consume any characters, so your matching position doesn't advance.

```
^\.(?=a)$
```

Matches the beginning of line (`^` -- this matches) followed by a literal `.` (`\.` -- this also matches), and then (without consuming any characters), checks to see if the next character is a literal `a` (`(?=a)`).  It is, so the lookahead matches.  It then asserts that your position is at the end of the string (`$`).  This is *not* the case, because we're still right after the `.`, so the match fails.

Another possible matching expression would be

```
^\.(?=a$)
```

Which works just as above, but the assertion about the end of the line is contained in the lookahead, so this time, it matches.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is only going to match a period that's followed by an 'a', without including 'a' in the match.
Another issue is that you're using $ after a character that's basically being ignored.

Remove the $ and it will work as described.

Bonus: I've enjoyed using this lately http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: regex101.com is another useful regex testing site